# Resize UITableView with Auto Layout with programming

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UITableView` dynamically loading data from a remote XML. It has 1 prototype cell of height = 70.

I try to set the height of the `UITableView` to:

> Cell Height x Number of Rows

using `[tbl setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 70 * contents.count)];` but the table size remains unchanged.

Since I'm using **Auto Layout**, some suggests that I should use:

```
[tbl setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

Added, but size remains unchanged.

How to change the size of the `UITableView` in order to fit exactly the size of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your tableView is anchored on top side, and it's height is unconstrained (use a placeholder intrinsicSize to allow this on the interface builder), you can extend UITableView into something like this and you won't need any code:

```
@implementation ExpandedTableView

- (void)reloadData
{
    [super reloadData];
    [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    return self.contentSize;
}

@end
```

Comment: what should be the values of `intrinsicSize` set in Interface Builder? Extending the `UITableView` sounds like an overkill...

Comment: It doesn't really matter. all those values do is make the interface builder not complain about missing constraints. The values will be given by the intrinsic size in runtime (IB Complains because by default UITableView doesn't have any)